# Modifying a string under a specific condition

Tags: python, string, tuples

In a Python program, I am trying to modify a string under a specific condition:

```
X = ('4c0')
Sig = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'e']
```

Sig is a list. Additionally, I have a tuple:

```
T = (4,'d',5)
```

If the second element (T[1]) is not in Sig, I must create another string, starting from X:

- as T[1] ('d') is not in Sig, T[2] must replace T[0] in X ('5' replacing '4');
- the last element in X must be added by 1 ('1' replacing '0').

In this case, the desired result should be:

```
Y = ('5c1')
```

I made this code but it is not add any string to Y:

```
Y = []
for i in TT: # TT has the tuple T
    i = list(i)
    if i[1] not in Sig:
        for j in TT:
            if type(j[2]) == str:
                if i[1] == j[1]:
                    Y.append(j[2][0]+i[1]+str(int(j[2][2]+1)))
```

Any ideas how I could solve this problem?

Comment: Please create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/. You have many `if` conditions in your logic. You should try to check that they are behaving as you expect them to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of missing conditions in your problem statement (e.g. what to do if 'd' was in Sig, How to handle values past 9, what if X[0] is not the same as T[0], what if X[2] is equal to T[2])

For the example given a simple string format should suffice:

```
X   = ('4c0')
Sig = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'e']
T   = (4,'d',5)

if T[1] not in Sig:
    Y = f"{T[2]}{X[1]}{int(X[2])+1}"

print(Y) # 5c1
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention it. There is no values above 9.

Answer (score 2):

You need to be more clear as to what the conditions are if this is a **one-time requirement** you can use -

```
i = 1
if T[i] not in sig:

  Y=list(X) # converting the string to a list in order to perform operations

  Y[i-1] = T[i+1] # operation 1 [replace element at position -1 as compared to Tuple element position check]

  Y[-1] = int(Y[-1])+1 # operation 2 [add 1 to the last element]

print(''.join(map(str, Y)))

'5c1'
```